# Codeigniter sending 2 values to the view from controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Im trying to send 2 values to the view to be used from the controller.

```
$data1= $this->datalib->is_data();
$data2['name']=$this->namelib->getName();
```

Im looking to send data1 and data2 so i can use both in two places. What changes i need?

```
 $this->load->view('person_view', array('value'=> $data1));
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just add $data1 to the $data array, like this;

```
$data['name'] = $this->namelib->getName();
$data['is_data'] = $this->datalib->is_data();
```

Then, pass the $data array to the view;

```
$this->load->view('person_view', $data);
```

You will be able to access the data array from the view, like this;

```
print_r($name);
print_r($is_data);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$data['info1']= $this->datalib->is_data();
$data['info2']=$this->namelib->getName();
```

Pass array `$data` to view,

```
$this->load->view('person_view',$data);
```

In your view `person_view.php` you can get the values of `info1` and `info2`. Like,

```
print_r($info1);
print_r($info2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job

```
$this->load->view('person_view', array('data1'=> $data1,'data2'=>$data2));
```

Comment: helped me get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this

```
$data['temp']= $this->datalib->is_data();
$data['name']=$this->namelib->getName();
```

Then pass data to view

```
 $this->load->view('person_view', $data);
```

In view you can use that two variables as $temp and $name.

```
echo $temp;
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
$data['data1']= $this->datalib->is_data();
$data['name']=$this->namelib->getName();
```

Then pass `$data` to the view

```
$this->load->view('person_view', $data);
```

In the view, use `$data1` and `$name` to access these values.

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
$dataToShow['data'] = $this->datalib->is_data();
$dataToShow['name'] = $this->namelib->getName();
```

then to load view

```
 $this->load->view('person_view', $dataToShow);
```

so you can access your data on your view with using this variable

```
 $data and $name
```

hope will help cheers

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. this was the change i needed, ty @Rupam was looking for something like that.

```
$this->load->view('person_view', array('value'=> $data1,'name'=>$data2['name']));
```